# How do I get around this tkinter error and make Radiobutton work?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I'm trying to create a small application that substitutes certain words of a file and then generates an output file. I'm stuck here. I want to get data from Radiobutton which then would be written to output file when the event is called.

Content of input.txt:
Name: string_replace1
ID Card: string_replace2
Island: string_replace2

My code so far:

```
    from tkinter import *
import re
from tkinter import messagebox

def save_info():
    Name_info = Name.get()
    IDCard_info = IDCard.get()
    Gender_info = Gender.get()

    filename = 'input.txt'
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        filename2 = "output.txt"
        with open(filename2, 'w') as f1:
          text = f.read()
          text = re.sub('string_replace1', Name_info, text)
          text = re.sub('string_replace2', IDCard_info, text)
          text = re.sub('string_replace3', Gender_info, text)
          f1.seek(0)
          f1.write(text)
          f1.truncate()
          messagebox.showinfo("Message", "Info Generated.")

app = Tk()

app.geometry("220x380")

app.title("Info Generator")

heading = Label(text="Info Generator", fg="black", width="500", height="3", font="10")

heading.pack()

Name_text = Label(text="Name :")
IDCard_text = Label(text="ID Card :")
Gender_text = Label(text="Gender :")

Name_text.place(x=15, y=70)
IDCard_text.place(x=15, y=140)
Gender_text.place(x=15, y=210)

Name = StringVar()
IDCard = StringVar()
Gender = IntVar()

Name_entry = Entry(textvariable=Name, width="30")
IDCard_entry = Entry(textvariable=IDCard, width="30")
Gender1_rbtn = Radiobutton(app, text="Female", variable=Gender, value="1")
Gender2_rbtn = Radiobutton(app, text="Male", variable=Gender, value="0")

Name_entry.place(x=15, y=100)
IDCard_entry.place(x=15, y=180)
Gender1_rbtn.place(x=15, y=240)
Gender2_rbtn.place(x=15, y=260)

button = Button(app, text="Generate Info", command=save_info, width="25", height="2", bg="grey")

button.place(x=15, y=290)


mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please provide a [mre] for us and give us some informations about the error and how your code behaves different from the way you intended it.

Answer (score 1):

This question would have been much easier to answer if you would have provided the stack trace of the occurring exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "demo.py", line 18, in save_info
    text = re.sub('string_replace3', Gender_info, text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 326, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 317, in _compile_repl
    return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 879, in parse_template
    s = Tokenizer(source)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 227, in __init__
    string = str(string, 'latin1')
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, int found
```

The problematic line is

```py
text = re.sub('string_replace3', Gender_info, text)
```

While `Name_info` and `IDCard_info` are strings, `Gender_info` is an int value as it stems from the radio button.

A quick fix would be to convert the number into a string like this:

```py
gender = "male" if Gender_info == 0 else "female"
text = re.sub('string_replace3', gender, text)
```

This got rid of the exception and generated a proper output file on my machine.

In case you want the number 0 or 1 in your output file, use the following instead:

```py
text = re.sub('string_replace3', gender, str(Gender_info))
```